# z3: A formula and its negation are unsatisfiable

Tags: z3, smt

A formula and its negation are both unsatisfiable.

http://rise4fun.com/Z3/qJHD

```
(define-fun max1 ((x Int) (y Int)) Int
    (ite (< y x) x y))

(define-fun myMax ((a Int) (b Int)) Int
    (ite (< a b) (- b 1) 0))


(define-const f Bool 
(forall ((a Int) (b Int))
(=> (exists ((i Int)) (and (<= (+ a 1) i) (< i b)))
(= (myMax a b) (max1 a (myMax (+ a 1) b))))))

(assert f)
;(assert (not f))

(check-sat)
```

Can someone please help me understand? I was expecting one of them to be sat. 
Note that both the functions max1 and myMax are defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the module that attempts to eliminate quantified variables using Fourier Motzkin elimination. A fix will be checked into the master branch now.

Comment: Fix commit link: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/54e8612f4d8e11f256a64044f2b35af48a0f2bec